# How List and Set interface add and remove object in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, copy

I have two collections from java.util package. Initially few elements added to it, and then removed the elements.I am trying to understand two things here.

Question 1: Are the removing element from both collections index based or element based? Below code which is compiled and run in eclipse.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = -3; i < 3; i++) {
                list.add(i);
                set.add(i);
            }
//List = [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2] Set =[-1, 0, -2, 1, -3, 2]
```

Now trying to delete the elements from both collections:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
   list.remove(i);
   set.remove(i);
  }
// Result is List = [-2, 0, 2] Set = [-1, -2, -3]
```

Question2: Looking at implementation code of java source for removing an element. How do I understand below source code?

```
 protected transient int modCount = 0;
 private int size;
 transient Object[] elementData;

 private void fastRemove(int index) {
   modCount++;
   int numMoved = size - index - 1;
   if (numMoved > 0)
      System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,numMoved);     
      elementData[--size] = null; 
   }
```

Comment: What is unclear about the code? Did you step through it in your debugger? What do you not understand?

Comment: Yes, I check in the debugger. While adding an element in the list it gets appended and while removing it gets remove from last element meaning it is resizing the array list. I am trying to understand why it returns -2,0,2.  I understood the case of Set as it removes the object and not the index element.

Comment: Also, My question to people who mark this as negative. Am I asking wrong questions that people are marking it negative?

Comment: Both of your questions are vague. The code and output make sense, and it's unclear what exactly you're stuck on.

Comment: Be aware that if `i` is an `int`, then for a `List`, the code `remove(i)` will remove the element in position `i`, no matter what that happens to be; whereas for a `Set`, there's generally no such concept as "position `i`", so the code `remove(i)` just removes the element `i`.

Comment: @shmosel I think my questions are pretty simple in layman language. And also people are answering to it also. Is my questions invalid asking here then tell me? I did some debug n then I asked.

Comment: The "people answering to it" is me. And I still believe your question could be improved. Perhaps not invalid, but not a model question either. For the record, I didn't downvote you.

Comment: Keep in mind. a "simple" question is not necessarily a good one. People ask simple questions all the time, like "How do I print such a pattern?" or "Why am I getting this exception?", but they're still not good questions because they don't show research effort and aren't specific enough. See also [ask].

Comment: @DavidWallace thank you for replying. In List if it removes element based on position then I am removing 0,1,2 position. So after removing it should return 0,1,2 but it returns [-2, 0, 2]. I am still trying to understand that.

Comment: Thank you @shmosel . I will try to improve my question.

Comment: After index 0 is removed, index 1 points to `-1`. After index 1 is removed, index 2 points to `1`. The result is `[-2, 0, 2]`, as you've observed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133772/discussion-between-vimal-panchal-and-shmosel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your first question, `set.remove(i)` calls [`Set#remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#remove-java.lang.Object-), which removes an element by value. `List` also has a `remove(Object)` method (inherited from `Collection`), but since `i` is `int`, `list.remove(i)` resolves to the more specific [`List#remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-), which removes an element by index.

As for your second question, the code is removing the element at the given index by shifting left all items to the right of it, then decrementing the size. See the javadoc to [`System#arraycopy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-) for specifics.

Comment: After discussion with @shmosel. Once element gets deleted from the list it **reindex** the list again and then removes the index based element. Hence marking this as an answer.